# call javascript from windows service... possible?

Tags: .net, web-services, windows-services

This is a task I have and I am a little unsure about the way to go about achieving this. So I thought the best approach would be to ask other professionals for their thoughts.

Basically, I will be storing a load of transactions/triggers for numerous affiliates in a database. Then using a widows service I am going to go through this database getting these transactions and then somehow invoke several different affiliate tracking sources.

Things such as Conversion Tracking, tracking pixels, or javascript tracking methods.

The general use case for these things are on a confirmation page, but as the system that this runs from has several "products" by different affiliates, and it depends on whether you got to the site from google or yahoo etc.

So a different tracking method could be used each time something is purchased. Depends on the configured triggers.

My question is how would someone go about developing such an application, where the tracking is stored in a central database and then processed based on a set of pre-defined triggers.

I was thinking I could maybe do something with wget.exe, but am unsure what the best approach would be.

Has anyone done anything similar, is this even a good idea??

I will also need to inject values into the tracking objects for things like ordervalue and reference number.

Am really gratefull for your thoughts.

an example of what I need to call:

```
<script language="javascript" src="https://scripts.affiliatefuture.com/AFFunctions.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
   var merchantID = 4197 ;
   var orderValue = 'ORDER_VALUE';
   var orderRef = 'ORDER_REF';
   var payoutCodes = '';
   var offlineCode = '';
   AFProcessSaleV2(merchantID, orderValue, orderRef,payoutCodes,offlineCode);
</script>
```

Another example of a different method:

```
<img src="https://www.emjcd.com/u?CID=<ENTERPRISEID>&OID=<OID>&TYPE=<ACTIONID>&ITEM1=<ITEMID>&AMT1=<AMT>&QTY1=<QTY>&CURRENCY=<CURRENCY>&METHOD=IMG" height="1" width="20">
```

Would it even be possible to do something with web request? Like this?

```
System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URI);
req.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(ProxyString, true); //true means no proxy
System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse()
```

Although I do not think that would run any returned javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is just not possible!!

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979098/wpf-design-considerations-using-webbrowser-control) is related and is the way I went about doing it.